# What is the cause of the epenthetic ‘r’ in ‘warsh’?

Tags: accent, american-english, rhoticity

Why does this ‘r’ appear only in ‘wash’ and ‘Washington’ without analogous examples? That is, why does this ‘r’ not also appear in similar constructions (like ‘posh’ (which is never pronounced ‘parsh’) or ‘to josh’ (which never allows for ‘I was jorshing/jarshing’))?

Comment: Tagged as `american-english` per @hippietrail’s suggestion.

Comment: fdb deleted their answer, but I would've said the same thing that I've never heard of this in any variety of English. It sounds like some strange American counterpart to [intrusive r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R#Intrusive_R)??

Comment: It's a regional peculiarity, reported from several places. In particular, it's part of my own speech, from DeKalb County, IL. It's very specific about lexical items, limited only to (1) _wash_ and all its forms (_washed, washes, washing_), (2) the proper noun _Washington_ (both as G. Washington's surname, and as the name of the capital city **and** of the state where I now live), and also (3) the interjection _Gosh!_. The intrusive /r/ is perhaps conditioned by the fact that it always precedes a palatal /ʃ/, not unlike the "ruki rule" of Sanskrit retroflexion of /s/ to /ṣ/ after /r, u, k, i/.

Comment: I'm from Washington State, and I've heard it occasionally.

Comment: My father from Michigan City, IN has this feature in his English.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it seems to be the case that you do get /r/ in those contexts and specific words (also, 'squash', etc.). It may be difficult to find them in text (e.g., for 'posh': 'porsh' and 'parsh' are both problematic for the speller), but they likely exist. I was able to find Google hits for 'jarsh'/'jarshing'/'jorshing', for example.

It is also possible that this kind of regularization rule is applied more for high-frequency words than for low-frequency. If 'wash', 'water' are much higher frequency than 'posh', 'josh', then it's reasonable to see fewer instances of 'jarsh'.

Comment: There is a related phenomenon in rural Utah, which is a regular swap of /or/ and /ar/; it's much remarked-on locally. Many people do it. For them _car_ and _core_ are pronounced /kor/ and /kar/, respectively. Not the opposite, which is standard. There are local peculiarities, and the topic comes up whenever cities like Spanish Fork and American Fork are mentioned. Wayne Booth even wrote [a paper about it](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZcNLjmaYikMC&lpg=PA267&ots=O_8JL7DOAR&dq=wayne%20booth%20utah%20farkism&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=wayne%20booth%20utah%20farkism&f=false).